# Connect PC to an Android Device without external Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, android

I created a Restful web service using Jersey in Eclipse. I connected to the Web Service from My Android Device(v2.1 - HTC Hero) with using of a Router.

I do not have the Router no more. Is there any way to connect my Android device to the Web Service on my localhost via Wifi configuration ?

If yes, can you clarify it for me step by step? I appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You must tether your phone to your computer.

You will find the option to create a "portable WiFi hotspot". This will be in the options, under "wireless connections" "internet" or "tethering" (it depends on what version of android you have). Once you have turned on the hotspot (you can use the default name and no password, or press "settings" to configure it), you connect to your phone from your PC as you would to any other hotspot.

EDIT: If your phone cannot make a hotspot (it seems the `HTC Hero` cannot) you have two options:

1) if your phone is rooted, install WiFiTether ([code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/))

2) if you are running Windows Vista/7, install Connectify (`connectify.me`) to turn your PC into a hotspot, and then connect to it with your phone. You will find the phone's IP in Connectify's list of connected clients.

Once you're connected, make sure to set your firewall to allow connections to and from other computers in the network (I don't know how to use your firewall, but if you're running Windows Vista or 7, make sure to set it as a "home" network).

And you're done. Your phone's IP address can be found by going to "network connections" (in network & sharing centre in Vista & 7) and looking at the status of the WiFi adaptor. It will be the IP address labelled "default gateway".

Comment: Thanks for you reply, under **wireless and network** I have these options: **VPN setting** and **Mobile Network**. I could not find **hotspot**! As I said in the question, The Version is 2.1 and model is [HTC Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Hero)

Comment: @Ali: my mistake, the HTC Hero cannot make hotspots! Sorry about that. I've added in steps that should work for your phone.

Comment: I installed [connectify.me](http://www.connectify.me/download/?refid=) but when I wanted to `Start HotsPot` I got [an error.](http://support.connectify.me/entries/20868143-hostednetwork-errors) would you please clarify in your answer how to use `Connectify`. It has several options such as **Internet to Share, Share Over, Sharing Mode**

Comment: @Ali: If you are getting hostednetwork errors, it normally means that either you are running Windows XP (in which case it won't work), or you have disabled a network adapter it needs to run. Go into network connections, and enable any connections that have been disabled. For the record, the default settings should work for what you are trying to do.